# php limit offset distribution for multiple subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sorting, activerecord

I have the following piece of code to get a list of notification items:

```
public function actionMynotifications($offset,$auth_key)
{
 $limit = intval(1);
 while ($limit >= intval(5)) {
     //
 }
 $this->findA($offset,$limit,$userid);
 $this->findB($offset,$limit,$userid);
 $this->findC($offset,$limit,$userid);
 $this->findD($offset,$limit,$userid);
 $this->findE($offset,$limit,$userid);
```

As input the Url queries on it with increasing the `$offset`. And as a limit I want to have 5. But this is a list of different types that shall be sorted by the `created_at` that I enter so when it is one result that is returned as array:

```
$this->findA($offset,$limit,$userid)['created_at'];
```

My idea is to compare all the routes to find the "newest" `created_at` and repeat this until I have a list of 5 (limit) on `$offset` 0.

My problem is that I do not get an idea where to start for a performant comparison loop that does not result in many if else statements. $offset and $limit have to be consistent for results like because it is not clear where the youngest items are.

(offset=0/limit=5)
A
A
A
B
E

or (offset=5/limit=5)
A
A
A
B
E

A
C
D
A
B

Gladly I give more information when needed just comment it.

Or is it more intelligent to set an extra table for each user with abstractions that contains just the `created_at`,`type`(for table),`id` and is re-sorted completely in intervals to provide this?

Or maybe make this last in the cache. And query this.